# iframe good or bad for my MVC web-app scenario

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, iframe, jquery-ui-tabs

I've been working into intranet web solutions which are to be used by a specific set of users of a system - like supply chain management. No SEO or marketing - only easy of use and simplicity that appeals them and makes their task simple.

I'm using MVC2 with ASP.Net. I'll explain my scenario in generic terms. I've a page which has a tab view. The first tab loads a record from a master table and the other tabs load data for some details table. And ideal example would be like:

> - Tab 1: Add/Edit Customer (master) record
> - Tab 2: Add/Edit Orders for a Customer
> - Tab 3: Add/Edit Items for an Order (depends on tab 2)
> - Tab 4: Add/Edit different addresses for that Customer

I'm using jQuery ui tab. Now as per my knowledge of iframes - if I design this page(View) to include the first tab and its contents in one page(View) and the rest of the tabs have iframe in which I use separate pages(Views). In short - all the dependent tabs will have their separate pages.

The benefits I see -

> 1. The page becomes v.light and fast because while the user is working on
>    tab 1 the other tabs will be loading
>    their iframe.
> 2. Functionally, each tab has to have its own Add/Edit and list independent.
>    For example if I'm adding addresses
>    then only my address iframe will be
>    refreshed and the rest of the
>    tabs/pages need not postback and
>    reload the data.
> 3. Having a universal save/cancel feature would require a v.complex
>    in-memory caching of the object
>    hierarchy if everything is in a single
>    page(View). I can use user-controls
>    (i.e. .ascx) but still processing
>    everything in a single action is like
>    huge & complex.
> 4. I need not worry about SEO or bookmarks or dynamic dimensions.
>    Instead I'm getting SOC (Separation of
>    concerns), everything is being
>    distributed v.well and the main thing
>    is that it becomes extremely fast as
>    the postbacks are separate.

.. all this if I get to use iframes :) However, I don't see many people like iframes like:
[Are iframes a terrible idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96748/are-iframes-a-terrible-idea)

If so - is there an equivalent jQuery alternative? I'd expect it to have the benefits of iframe and atleast the feature to load the content dynamically via url and separate postbacks. I don't want to create a messy AJAX blob which can handle things but make the backend equally complex.

> Kindly let me know your thoughts - I
> don't want to know how good/bad
> iframes are, I just want to know what
> suits my requirements and if there's a
> better alternative to iframes .. for
> my scenario.

**EDIT #1:** I got a list of iframe supporting browsers -

http://www.webmaster-resources101.com/articles/view/417/

**EDIT #2:** I got something that might be a stepping stone towards a better optioninstead of iframe -

Its a combination of two jQuery plugins on is the famous jQuery tabs plugin and another is the adhoc plugin which can control the postback of a container.

> jQuery ui tab:
> http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/
>
> jquery-hijack:
> http://code.google.com/p/jquery-hijack/

Can this work? Any other better options like this?

Comment: iframe is bad. Always bad. Bad bad bad. Just use hidden divs. Use partial postbacks and ajax.

Comment: Pls do not stick to a Myth - if you say its bad also provide me a better alternative. Hidden DIVs are no good for the features I've mentioned with iframes.

Comment: @HermantTank Iframes are not the semantic HTML answer to your problem.

Comment: I agree with @Raynos.  There are better ways.

Comment: @HermantTank that articles looks like it was written in 1998. Everything it's mentioned is wrong given the current web development climate. [Read the infamous AJAX article](http://www.adaptivepath.com/ideas/ajax-new-approach-web-applications)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to get off this post to complete it - [Alternative for iframes for jQuery ui tabs plugin - with support for postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584632/alternative-for-iframes-for-jquery-ui-tabs-plugin-with-support-for-postback)

I didn't wanted a fully "JSified" ajax base model handling because it brings the business object level details in the presentation layer. So, to keep it abstract I ended up using a jQuery plugin jquery.forms.js which allows to ajaxify my forms.

Combined with the "partial view" concept of MVC I was able to achieve a complete AJAX postback solution (without making it complex or bringing my model level handling on client side as features in knockoutjs, backbone, etc... (they're great but I wanted to keep thing simple and in control (on server side))

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

**TL;DR**

> Kindly let me know your thoughts - I don't want to know how good/bad iframes are, I just want to know what suits my requirements and if there's a better alternative to iframes .. for my scenario.

AJAX solves your client-server communication problems. There are plenty of client side libraries that make ajax very easy. For example [Backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) integrates with a RESTful service right out of the box.

Alternatives to AJAX are COMET and WebSockets.

**Thorough Reasoning**

> 1.The page becomes v.light and fast because while the user is working on tab 1 the other tabs will be loading their iframe.

- Iframes block onload of the main page

If you want to use onload handlers you have to wait for all iframes to load anyway.

The exact same concepts apply to loading HTML in order. I don't think HTML loading is a noticable bottleneck. I can't imagine getting a noticable speed increase from using iframes.

You may however get a noticable speed increase from using sensible HTML and lazy loading / pagination.

> 2.Functionally, each tab has to have its own Add/Edit and list independent. For example if I'm adding addresses then only my address iframe will be refreshed and the rest of the tabs/pages need not postback and reload the data.

Each tab should have it's own form instead that you can postback. If the user has JavaScript then you use ajax.

> 3.Having a universal save/cancel feature would require a v.complex in-memory caching of the object hierarchy if everything is in a single page(View). I can use user-controls (i.e. .ascx) but still processing everything in a single action is like huge & complex.

No. Use backbone/spine. Implement client side MVC and it's very simple and well structured.

> 4.I need not worry about SEO or bookmarks or dynamic dimensions. Instead I'm getting SOC (Separation of concerns), everything is being distributed v.well and the main thing is that it becomes extremely fast as the postbacks are separate.

Your still posting back rather then using ajax which is visually slower. Use proper HTML5 techiniques including client side MVC and it will distributed very well and extremely fast.

**Disadvantages:**

- Cross iframe communication is a right pain.

It slows you down, and is a pain to develop. All your content in iframes are hard coupled together because they all relate to one customer.

How are you going to handle changing the customer in the main tab? Are you going to *reload* the other 3 iframes to re-populate it with the correct data?

**That's very expensive and slow**

- Not semantic

> Contexts in which this element can be used: Where embedded content is expected.

Your tabs are not embedded content. There just normal HTML forms and they should be.

- Lack of code re-use across iframes as each has it's own code pool.

You also can't re-use elements and global data as each iframe is sandboxed. This means it's going to be a pain to extend for a fifth tab as you have to develop an entire new tab rather then plug into existing functionality.

I believe your main problem is not understanding that there are plenty of tools for writing high quality javascript applications to solve your problem for you.

Use [backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) or [spine](http://maccman.github.com/spine/) or [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/). You may also want to consider a templating engine of your choice (I would recommend EJS or Jade)

Comment: +1 for a clear list of disadvantages.  It just couldn't be more clear.

Comment: I wish I could give another +1 for saying:  _"I believe your main problem is not understanding that there are plenty of tools for writing high quality javascript applications to solve your problem for you."_

Comment: @Sparky672 I don't think it's _his_ problem per-se. I just believe he's reading articles and following teachings dated circa 2000 and just is not up to data with modern techniques. JS is a fast moving sector. The landscape was radically different 3 years ago.

Comment: @Raynos:  I understand.  It's clear he's quite behind in that regard.

Comment: Thanks. I know iframes are old but the situation demanded it. Its mandatory to keep things separate, a blob of code with lots of ajax triggers might get messy. I've worked with jquery and OOP in js but never done MVC via js. With the js extensions my primary concerns are speed and complexity. I don't do much in body onload. However, I can't imagine everything being rendered in the same page - these tabs are complex each can have a grid & form. I've visited the libraries Raynos mentioned. I'll need to get deeper but I was really hoping if there was a simpler alternative to iframes.

Comment: @HernantTank no. You can either **hack** it with iframes or you can just write solid well structured maintainable code in JavaScript. If you have strict deadlines feel free to take on code debt and hack it with iframes. The future maintainer of the project will hate you though.

Answer (score 0):

It is okay to use an `iframe` provided that you have the control over the browser which the application runs on.

Otherwise, you would run into problems like browser compatibility soon.

Comment: I would still recommend againts an iframe if your not using it to inject a 3rd party document into your page.

Comment: I've nothing like 3rd party, everything accessed is built by me. I don't have to make it commercial or go as low as support for IE3, etc.. Besides, atleast until I find something equivalent I've to settle with iframes, if there's nothing else which can load data dynamically.

Comment: @HermantTank There's this little thing called AJAX. It loads data dynamically.

Comment: @Raynos: I wouldn't have entered into this conversation if I was not far with jquery and knew that ajax could help replace iframes. I'm working on a corporate web solution and each page has a lot of things going on. Its not one of your shopping-list kind of web-app. I need something solid which helps me keep things separate without using iframes. ***Pls share if you find specific example/demo online.

Comment: @HermantTank There are many tools for structuring web pages. [Backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) and [Spine](http://maccman.github.com/spine/) give you clientside MVC libraries to control your code. Alternatively there are heavy weights like DOJO, Goog and YUI3. Gigantic web apps significantly more complex then yours are build on those.