# Alternative for iframes for jQuery ui tabs plugin - with support for postback

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, iframe

Actually this is a more specific version of a question I posted in past regarding iframe -

> [iframe good or bad for my MVC web-app scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421989/iframe-good-or-bad-for-my-mvc-web-app-scenario)

The above post ended up into being more inclined towards "iframes are bad" where as I was actually looking for a solid iframe equivalent (if iframes are really bad for my scenario). They almost hanged me :) but I was just trying to derive a better alternative. Some suggested me to consider an AJAX library which would bring the MVC processing on client-side, **too complex**. The post is still frozen.

Anyway, let me simplify. I'm using jQuery UI tabs plugin to display a tab-view. I want to isolate the tab content pages because they manage (add\edit) separate entities. Each tab postback/validation has to be isolated - so that **processing in a tab doesn't 'disturb' the other one**. iframes are serving the purpose v.well and I've already handled the issues like session timeout, etc.. but experts say 'iframes are bad' so I've started looking for alternatives. Hope you've understood what I want - a replacement for iframe for isolated functionality.

Here're some alternatives I've found -

1. **jQuery UI tabs** does allow dynamic loading if we specify it in Better alternative to an iframe?
   This was perfect until I got stuck into cross tab validation issues unlike iframe this is NOt isolated and postback in one tab tries to postback the whole page (i.e. all the tabs).
2. For the problem mentioned in (1.) I came across a plugin which is able to limit the postback to a container. (**jQuery UI tab + jquery-hyjack**) Looks promising -
   http://code.google.com/p/jquery-hijack/
3. I've got tons of solutions like inline **rendering of tabs in DIV, server-side includes**, etc.. but this takes me back to the original issue of isolation. Postback/validation of one tab triggers validation in other tabs. Also I don't like the idea of loading the whole page because of postback in a single tab (other tabs stay unaffected).
4. Some say this works better then iframe -

> object
>   classid="clsid:25336920-03F9-11CF-8FD0-00AA00686F13"
>   type="text/html" data="xpto.html"
>   width="300" height="300">

(5.) I've gone thru some popular blogs, forums to find the issues of iframe like -
http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/html/frames/pros-cons.html (its about frames but some of it applied to iframe as well)

> If I'm not concerned about SEO,
>   linking/bookmarks and I've handled the
>   iframe navigation, security and
>   session timeout/redirection issues -
>   do the iframes still disqualify for my
>   scenario?

**Please suggest and provide a worth solution.**

Some links for iframe info:

- http://www.webmasterworld.com/google/3569863.htm
- pros & cones: http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081106232754AA9a1SC
- iframe support: http://www.webmaster-resources101.com/articles/view/417/
- iframe is in w3c: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#h-16.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using ASP.NET MVC (based on the other post), you have control over the Form tag, if you enclose each tab within it's own form tag you will have tab-specific fields in each Postback making it 'isolated' the way you envisioned, but it is still a full post in the page -- it seems you are stuck a little with the WebForms mantra which is understandable.

You could also serialize the tab-specific fields in JSON + jQuery in a tab and create a post on the fly using an AJAX to another endpoint like an ASHX/RESTful API able to handle your validation.

EDIT: on the IFRAMES tho, if you are using tabs it means you should be talking about information under the same context, then SEO and all that should not be an issue. All popups in my (intranet) app I work at the moment are iframes, but you have to think about the **back button** a lot when designing for those.

Comment: The main page has jQuery ui tab and within it are the iframes so the back-button in browser didn't cause issue (besides its not the usual flow). Yes I can have separate forms but a full-postback means the other tabs will be reinitialized - lot of unnecessary bandwidth. BTW, any idea about the jquery-hyjack plugin I've mentioned?

Comment: Dont know the plugin. (Separated forms OR create the post on the fly) + Ajax, no full postback, saved bandwidth.

Comment: With all do respect to the dynamic content loading features with jQuery + AJAX - is that really worth? Esp when I've already handled the iframe concerns in my tab-view page. My site needs no SEO, I need no cross-iframe communication and iframes provide the perfect isolation. With AJAX approach I see more complexity/layers I need to make my MVC Action return the html-rendered by View instead of simply returning a View and also I've got to handle the dynamic loading. Full-postback with isolated forms will make it too heavy!

Comment: One more fact I've learned is that facebook, twitter even yahoo uses iframes. "frame" is depricated "iframe" is standardised in HTML 4.0 and supported in the HTML 5. And the famous Gmail - its based on iframes. With iframes I can make pages in tabs re-usable as separate dialogs in other pages because their processing is completely isolated be it iframe or a dialog. If I had static pages - I'd have opted iframe but my pages are dynamic and do a lot of postback/processing. I'm happy to migrate if there a better replacement for iframes which has all this or even most of it?

Comment: You seem to have made a rhetorical question then, since you want to use IFRAMES, not an alternative to it. IF you go with the usability you will have trouble with it, twitter, facebook and others measured how important it was for them and decided accordingly, you should do the same.

Comment: I ended up using jQuery.forms.js - a plugin which allows to ajaxify forms. I used a "partial view" with each of my tabs to isolate and where ever needed each tab had its own form. So, I'm able to achieve a compete ajax solution without iframes / frames. I'll thank Aquino for the clue.